# Stump with the array modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

From the image I was trying to generate a building using a plane for this tutorial series I am following. Now my problem is with the empty object once I add it and set the *Array* to *Object Offset* I rotate it to 90 degrees on the x axis (as its the horizontal axis ) but look at it it segments into smaller pieces and refuses to at least look like they are joined. I am stumped.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: hello, make sure that you've applied the scale of the empty

Comment: hi i already did that it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Check my edits on the answer.

Comment: Check my edit # 2 on the answer. It solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Move the top array modifier underneath the one under it. It will solve the problem.

Edit: Select your building, go to Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry. Then select the empty, then select the building and press Shift + Z > Selection to active. Now go into front view mode, select your empty, and scale on the Z-axis after zooming into the top and press the Shift key so you can do it accurately. Your building will now be even. I do not know why did you use an empty as an object offset, the better solution would be disabling object offset, but if you want it this is a temporary solution.

**Edit 2:** Ignore everything I mentioned above. Just follow the video setup, select your object (the building base mesh) and press Ctrl+A>Apply Scale. Your building will now be the same height, and it would be exactly like the tutorial.

Comment: yeah thank you  but it presents another problem which is that they are not the same height

Comment: @AustinMgbolu That's because of the empty. Is the empty there for some specific reason? Disabling object offset on the array modifier fixes the height problem.

Comment: @AustinMgbolu Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: its the tutorial T_T

Comment: @AustinMgbolu can you attach the link of the tutorial?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfD9Nc1KmYM&list=RDCMUCHihootMqyGz175gqOPahtw&index=3

Comment: @AustinMgbolu Problem solved....